# Is this enough for unit testing a basic controller?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

My pet project, is a [community driven lyrics archive](https://bejebeje.com), it is still a work in progress, and all code is [open sourced on GitHub](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje).

I have a local git branch `tests/add-controller-tests` where I wish to add some unit tests on my controllers. I have purposefully kept my controllers basic, for example here is my `HTTP GET Index` action on the `HomeController`:

```
namespace Bejebeje.Mvc.Controllers
{
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Bejebeje.Models.Lyric;
  using Bejebeje.Services.Services.Interfaces;
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
  using Models;

  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    private readonly IArtistsService _artistsService;

    private readonly ILyricsService _lyricsService;

    public HomeController(
      IArtistsService artistsService,
      ILyricsService lyricsService)
    {
      _artistsService = artistsService;
      _lyricsService = lyricsService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
      IndexViewModel viewModel = new IndexViewModel();

      viewModel.Lyrics = await _lyricsService
        .GetRecentLyricsAsync();

      viewModel.FemaleArtists = await _artistsService
        .GetTopTenFemaleArtistsByLyricsCountAsync();

      return View(viewModel);
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
      ErrorViewModel viewModel = new ErrorViewModel
      {
        RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier,
      };

      return View(viewModel);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my unit test (just one):

```
namespace Bejebeje.Mvc.Tests.Controllers
{
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Bejebeje.Models.Artist;
  using Bejebeje.Models.Lyric;
  using FluentAssertions;
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
  using Moq;
  using Mvc.Controllers;
  using NUnit.Framework;
  using Services.Services.Interfaces;

  [TestFixture]
  public class HomeControllerTests
  {
    [Test]
    public async Task Index_ReturnsAViewResult_WithAnIndexViewModel()
    {
      // arrange
      IEnumerable<ArtistItemViewModel> tenFemaleArtists = new List<ArtistItemViewModel>
      {
        new ArtistItemViewModel
        {
          FirstName = "A1",
          LastName = "A1",
          ImageAlternateText = "A1",
          ImageUrl = "A1",
          PrimarySlug = "A1",
        },
        new ArtistItemViewModel
        {
          FirstName = "A2",
          LastName = "A2",
          ImageAlternateText = "A2",
          ImageUrl = "A2",
          PrimarySlug = "A2",
        },
        new ArtistItemViewModel
        {
          FirstName = "A3",
          LastName = "A3",
          ImageAlternateText = "A3",
          ImageUrl = "A3",
          PrimarySlug = "A3",
        },
        new ArtistItemViewModel
        {
          FirstName = "A4",
          LastName = "A4",
          ImageAlternateText = "A4",
          ImageUrl = "A4",
          PrimarySlug = "A4",
        },
        new ArtistItemViewModel
        {
          FirstName = "A5",
          LastName = "A5",
          ImageAlternateText = "A5",
          ImageUrl = "A5",
          PrimarySlug = "A5",
        },
        new ArtistItemViewModel
        {
          FirstName = "A6",
          LastName = "A6",
          ImageAlternateText = "A6",
          ImageUrl = "A6",
          PrimarySlug = "A6",
        },
        new ArtistItemViewModel
        {
          FirstName = "A7",
          LastName = "A7",
          ImageAlternateText = "A7",
          ImageUrl = "A7",
          PrimarySlug = "A7",
        },
        new ArtistItemViewModel
        {
          FirstName = "A8",
          LastName = "A8",
          ImageAlternateText = "A8",
          ImageUrl = "A8",
          PrimarySlug = "A8",
        },
        new ArtistItemViewModel
        {
          FirstName = "A9",
          LastName = "A9",
          ImageAlternateText = "A9",
          ImageUrl = "A9",
          PrimarySlug = "A9",
        },
        new ArtistItemViewModel
        {
          FirstName = "A10",
          LastName = "A10",
          ImageAlternateText = "A10",
          ImageUrl = "A10",
          PrimarySlug = "A10",
        }
      };

      Mock<IArtistsService> mockArtistsService = new Mock<IArtistsService>();

      mockArtistsService
        .Setup(x => x.GetTopTenFemaleArtistsByLyricsCountAsync())
        .ReturnsAsync(tenFemaleArtists);

      IEnumerable<LyricItemViewModel> tenRecentLyrics = new List<LyricItemViewModel>
      {
        new LyricItemViewModel
        {
          Title = "L1",
          LyricPrimarySlug = "L1",
          ArtistId = 1,
          ArtistName = "L1",
          ArtistPrimarySlug = "L1",
          ArtistImageUrl = "L1",
          ArtistImageAlternateText = "L1",
        },
        new LyricItemViewModel
        {
          Title = "L2",
          LyricPrimarySlug = "L2",
          ArtistId = 2,
          ArtistName = "L2",
          ArtistPrimarySlug = "L2",
          ArtistImageUrl = "L2",
          ArtistImageAlternateText = "L2",
        },
        new LyricItemViewModel
        {
          Title = "L3",
          LyricPrimarySlug = "L3",
          ArtistId = 3,
          ArtistName = "L3",
          ArtistPrimarySlug = "L3",
          ArtistImageUrl = "L3",
          ArtistImageAlternateText = "L3",
        },
        new LyricItemViewModel
        {
          Title = "L4",
          LyricPrimarySlug = "L4",
          ArtistId = 4,
          ArtistName = "L4",
          ArtistPrimarySlug = "L4",
          ArtistImageUrl = "L4",
          ArtistImageAlternateText = "L4",
        },
        new LyricItemViewModel
        {
          Title = "L5",
          LyricPrimarySlug = "L5",
          ArtistId = 5,
          ArtistName = "L5",
          ArtistPrimarySlug = "L5",
          ArtistImageUrl = "L5",
          ArtistImageAlternateText = "L5",
        },
        new LyricItemViewModel
        {
          Title = "L6",
          LyricPrimarySlug = "L6",
          ArtistId = 6,
          ArtistName = "L6",
          ArtistPrimarySlug = "L6",
          ArtistImageUrl = "L6",
          ArtistImageAlternateText = "L6",
        },
        new LyricItemViewModel
        {
          Title = "L7",
          LyricPrimarySlug = "L7",
          ArtistId = 7,
          ArtistName = "L7",
          ArtistPrimarySlug = "L7",
          ArtistImageUrl = "L7",
          ArtistImageAlternateText = "L7",
        },
        new LyricItemViewModel
        {
          Title = "L8",
          LyricPrimarySlug = "L8",
          ArtistId = 8,
          ArtistName = "L8",
          ArtistPrimarySlug = "L8",
          ArtistImageUrl = "L8",
          ArtistImageAlternateText = "L8",
        },
        new LyricItemViewModel
        {
          Title = "L9",
          LyricPrimarySlug = "L9",
          ArtistId = 9,
          ArtistName = "L9",
          ArtistPrimarySlug = "L9",
          ArtistImageUrl = "L9",
          ArtistImageAlternateText = "L9",
        },
        new LyricItemViewModel
        {
          Title = "L10",
          LyricPrimarySlug = "L10",
          ArtistId = 10,
          ArtistName = "L10",
          ArtistPrimarySlug = "L10",
          ArtistImageUrl = "L10",
          ArtistImageAlternateText = "L10",
        },
      };

      Mock<ILyricsService> mockLyricsService = new Mock<ILyricsService>();

      mockLyricsService
        .Setup(x => x.GetRecentLyricsAsync())
        .ReturnsAsync(tenRecentLyrics);

      HomeController homeController = new HomeController(mockArtistsService.Object, mockLyricsService.Object);

      // act
      IActionResult actionResult = await homeController.Index();

      // assert
      ViewResult view = actionResult.Should().BeOfType<ViewResult>().Subject;
      IndexViewModel viewModel = view.Model.Should().BeOfType<IndexViewModel>().Subject;
      viewModel.FemaleArtists.Should().HaveCount(10);
      viewModel.Lyrics.Should().HaveCount(10);
    }
  }
}
```

As far as tests concenrning the controller, is there anything else that I should test? Also, any other suggestions on naming or making things more readable ...etc

In my test, I can extract the code that builds the lists to a method, is there anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here are some quick observations about your implementation:

1. It does not handle faulty or malfunctioning cases:

   - What if one of the services fails?
   - What if one of the services responds quite slowly?
2. It does not take advantage of concurrent async calls

   - As I can see the `artistsService` call does not depend on the previous service call
   - You can run them concurrently like this or you can [further enhance it](https://www.meziantou.net/get-the-result-of-multiple-tasks-in-a-valuetuple-and-whenall.htm):

```cs
var recentLyrics =_lyricsService.GetRecentLyricsAsync();
var topTenFemailArtists = _artistsService.GetTopTenFemaleArtistsByLyricsCountAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(recentLyrics,  topTenFemailArtists);

viewModel.Lyrics = await recentLyrics;
viewModel.FemaleArtists = await topTenFemailArtists;
```

3. It relies on implicit routing

   - Make it explicit via the `HttpGetAttribute` ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.httpgetattribute)) then you can & should test this aspect as well:

```cs
[HttpGet, Route("Home/Index")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

4. `viewModel` is not really good name for your variable.

   - It uses [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) which should be avoided if possible.
5. Try to separate data retrieval and response creation.

   - It could help you a lot during debugging.

Now, let's review your test

1. First of all: naming. Please try to use the Given-When-Then structure in order to describe under what circumstances which method how should behave

   - In your case, for example: `GivenAFlawlessArtists_AndAFlawlessLyricsServices_WhenTheIndexActionIsCalled_ThenItFetchesDataFromTheServices_AndPopulatesTheResponseWithTheResults`
   - **Given** a flawless Artists And a flawless Lyrics Services
   - **When** the Index action is called
   - **Then** it fetches data from the Services And populates the response with the Results
   - It describe what do you except under certain conditions
2. As you have already mentioned the sample data generation could and should be extracted away.
3. The `homeController` is not a really good name. In general you can name it to `SUT`. This abbreviates the following: *System Under Test*.

   - It helps the reader of your code to remain focused.
4. It might make sense to perform deep comparison on your viewmodel as well

   - To make sure that the data is not changed / masked / tampered by the
     controller's action.

Comment: I agree with a lot of your points, however I don't see the problem with `viewModel`. Hungarian Notation means using the type of a variable in its name, but `viewModel` is just what the variable represents in the context of MVVM. I also think it is perfectly fine to keep the name `homeController` for the tests. `SUT` refers to a system, but unit tests usually test units, hence the term *Unit Under Test* (`UUT`) exists.

Comment: In terms of handling things going wrong, do I just wrap in a try / catch? and if error, redirect to an error controller/action?

Comment: @J86 As always it depends. Is there anything what you can do in case of failure?  For example perform a retry or fallback to another read replica, etc. If your ASP.NET application has been configured with a global error handler then you should not need to try/catch and manually redirect. ASP.NET will do that on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks, I really can't think of anything that would go wrong :/ I mean unless the database connection string is wrong, but there's not much we can do about that